# JClouds: How to list EC2 nodes in just one region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jclouds

Calling listNodes() on EC2 takes several minutes to run, because it queries each EC2 region in a row. This is a long time, especially if I know where I want to be looking for my nodes.

Any way of making the query more focused or otherwise more efficient?

Ideas:

1. Somehow customize the ComputeService to work with specific regions
2. Have all the queries run concurrently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to improve that.

- You can limit the regions jclouds will connect to by setting the `jclouds.regions` property to the comma separated list of the regions you want to use.
- You can configure filters for the queries that are performed to get the list of images by setting them in the [jclouds.ec2.ami-query](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/providers/aws-ec2/src/main/java/org/jclouds/aws/ec2/reference/AWSEC2Constants.java) property.

You can find the default values for both properties in the [AWSEC2ProviderMetadata](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/providers/aws-ec2/src/main/java/org/jclouds/aws/ec2/AWSEC2ProviderMetadata.java#L58-L76).

Comment: Thanks, will try that.